# Training Output of LIBLINEAR

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am trying the libSVM package, playing with RBF and Linear classification, and I followed (I think) all recommendations in their README files.

I have a big file to train on, (70K) so I am trying to use liblinear instead of RBF.

The only problem is that I am unable to get the model after the training phase, my command line looks like this :

```
./train -c 4 -v 5 -s 6 TrainingSet.scal TrainingSet.scal.Model
```

After the training is done, I have the accuracy estimation but then when I look at the *.model file to use it against my test set, I simply don't find it.

DO you think it is a bug in the package or is there something I am missing here ?

Thanks

Rad

Answer (score 2):

Option -v 5 means that you are doing 5-fold evaluation on training set. If this option is enabled, then liblinear estimates error using 5-fold evaluation and doesn't output model.

If you want to output model, then don't use -v 5. Tt doesn't output training error in that case. But you can use liblinear-predict to estimate error on test set.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the library directly on code, but I think in your case the training is not being performed because you are using the option -s 6 which I think is undefined.

This is the usage:

`
-s svm_type : set type of SVM (default 0)

```
0 -- C-SVC      (multi-class classification)
1 -- nu-SVC     (multi-class classification)
2 -- one-class SVM  
3 -- epsilon-SVR    (regression)
4 -- nu-SVR     (regression)
```

` 
You are also omitting the kernel type

```
-t kernel_type : set type of kernel function (default 2)
0 -- linear: u'*v
1 -- polynomial: (gamma*u'*v + coef0)^degree
2 -- radial basis function: exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)
3 -- sigmoid: tanh(gamma*u'*v + coef0)
4 -- precomputed kernel (kernel values in training_set_file)
```

Hopefully that would make the trick.

Comment: But I use liblinear package [link](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) and not the libsvm per se, their ./train programe has -s going to 13 as mentioned here [link](https://github.com/ninjin/liblinear/blob/master/README)

Comment: @Rad Hmm such a little detail :P I haven't used that version of the library but I will give it a look and let you know. Have you tried already with the normal libsvm?

Comment: I figured out that we dont have to use the -v option when we train after knowing the right parameters (no need for cross validation) then we have the output model

Comment: That's awesome! you should write the answer and approve it for future references :)